# Error while setting up Movesense platform with Cmake commands

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, movesense

I've been trying to set up movesense platform in my windows 10 machine and facing issues with cmake commands.

- I pulled the movesense container using docker

`docker pull movesense/sensor-build-env:latest`

- I cloned the movesense repo using the below code

`git clone git@bitbucket.org:suunto/movesense-device-lib.git`

- Then I moved to the cloned folder

`cd movesense-device-lib`

- Then I started the docker image on the terminal

`docker run -it --rm -v c:/My/Project/Folder/movesense-device-lib:/movesense:delegated movesense/sensor-build-env:latest`

- The docker prompted and I followed the below commands

`cd /movesense`
`mkdir myBuild`
`cd myBuild`

- Now, I ran the CMake "Run the CMake (needs to be done only once unless you add files to the project). It's possible to build both the debug and release version. In both cases the command will contain the following:" by the following command

`cmake -G Ninja -DMOVESENSE_CORE_LIBRARY=../MovesenseCoreLib/ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../MovesenseCoreLib/toolchain/gcc-nrf52.cmake <sample_directory>`

I created a sample folder as build1 and saved. In the place of **sample_directory**, I pasted "**build**" and executed the command.
But in return I get an error as

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/movesense/myBuild/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt. Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

**The objective is to create a project as zip file and run it in visual studio. Please help me to solve the issue. I've attached the links of the documents which I followed from movesense.**

[**Movesense Set up document**](http://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/getting_started/)

Comment: Seems you forget to add '..'  to the command line to provide the correct location of the CMakeLists.txt file. You are inside of the build directory and the source directory is one level up.

Comment: Where should I add '..' Can you please specify?

Comment: To the end of the CMake command line.

Comment: Tried with only '..' at end, tried with ..build, tried with ../build. No change, same error

Comment: Please glance the document which I attached. You'll get some idea.

Comment: You need to locate the top level CMakeLists.txt file of the movesense library and provide the path to it at last argument of the CMake command line. That's how CMake configuration step works.

Comment: OK. back on the desktop I think I figured out what is needed as last argument:  The template engine of the website makes it hard to understand the directions given: *Note that the means the relative path to the CMakeLists.txt file of the application desired to be built. For example: ../samples/hello_world_app*. It is missing <sample_directory> string here. So try to provide `../samples/hello_world_app` as last argument to your CMake command line.

Comment: I've solved that issue. Now I'm unable to add path of CMake CXX compliler, I'm getting this sort of error :  ` Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH`"  **Please help me**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "<sample_directory>" should be a path to the folder where the firmware source code is (i.e. the sample app folder). If you create the build folder as /movesense/myBuild and cd into it, the path would be *../samples/blinky_app* if you are building the blinky_app -sample.

*Full disclosure: I work for the movesense team*